# Event to trigger when admin Hold an order

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I would like to send intimation to other third party tool if admin hold any order.

Is there any Event observer available to trigger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have detected 2 events for "hold" action: `controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_hold` and `controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_hold`.

Next time, when you need to detect if an event has been dispatched add `Mage::log($name, null, 'events.log', true);` in `app/Mage.php` on `dispatchEvent` function. `events.log` file will be created under you `var/log` folder. In this file you will find all the events that has been dispatched.

Your function will become:

```
public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
    {
        Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
        $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
        Mage::log($name, null, 'events.log', true);
        Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
        return $result;
    }
```

Good luck !